# jQuery: Variable ID not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a key press function that changes where the cursor lies in an input field. It works when the jQuery id is simply "body" but then the keydown works everywhere. Instead I want the keydown to only work in the most recently generated input field. See the code below.

```
var ui_pc = 3001;

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#"+ui_pc+"input").keydown(function(e){
    var press = e.which;
    press = press.toString();
    if(e.which=="13") {
      ui_pc++;
      $("#main").append("<div id=\"" + ui_pc + "\"><input id=\""+ ui_pc+ "input\"></input></div>");
      document.getElementById(ui_pc+"input").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

Since the cursor starts in line 3001, when you put the cursor there it works fine. However, the function does not update i.e. the function only works only on div "#3001input" and does not update with the variable named pc_ui.

Why is this the case? I think it has something to do with closures in JS?

Comment: on keydown event, it changes the value of ui_pc++ but it doesnt call the event again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must to change to a delegation events method:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '[id$="input"]', function(e){
   //your stuff
});
```

**Why this?**

This is produced because you are attaching the events to the existing elements when DOM ready, but not for new elements created. To avoid this, use this delegation method and it works.

See  more:

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: He increments the counter for the `ID` attribute added to new elements, your code wouldn't work since it uses the same ID

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind from previous input and bind to latest input since you want it to work on most recently generated input field.

```js
var ui_pc = 3001;

$(document).ready(function(){
 bindToNewInput();
});

function appendNewInput(e)
{
 var press = e.which;
 press = press.toString();
 if(e.which=="13") {
   ui_pc++;
   $("#main").append("<div id=\"" + ui_pc + "\"><input id=\""+ ui_pc+ "input\"></input></div>");
   document.getElementById(ui_pc+"input").focus();
   bindToNewInput();
 }
}

function bindToNewInput()
{
 $("#"+(ui_pc-1)+"input").off('keydown');

 $("#"+ui_pc+"input").keydown(function(e){
  appendNewInput(e);
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
 <input id="3001input" type="text"/>
</div>
```